# JS: Removing Object from json array with array

Tags: javascript, json

im trying to remove from my JSON file one object from the array:

```
let json = [{
              "name":"John",
              "age":"29"
             },
             {
              "name":"Billy",
              "age":"45"
           }];
```

I have an array that has the data to remove from JSON, it only has name in it

```
let remObj = ['John'];
```

Is it possible to remove only using name?

Edit:
I have tried Slice, Splice and filter

Comment: `json.filter(p => !remObj.includes(p.name))`

Comment: Please note that `let json` means the data is just normal javascript data, not JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```js
let json = [{
              "name":"John",
              "age":"29"
             },
             {
              "name":"Billy",
              "age":"45"
           }];

let remObj = ['John'];

const newJson = json.filter(p => !remObj.includes(p.name))
console.log(newJson)
```